# list of string in prolog

Tags: string, list, prolog

How i can break the list of string  into two halves to process these halves

Answer (score 2):

For example with code similar to:

```
length(String, L),
H is L // 2,
length(First_Half, H),
append(First_Half, Second_Half, String)
```